# QuickBlox: How to change password of user after login?

Tags: quickblox

Is there any way to change password of the user after login ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure

```
QBUUser *user = [QBUUser user];
user.ID = 300;
user.oldPassword = @"fgrhpass";
user.password = @"newpassword";

[QBUsers updateUser:user delegate:self];
```